# Prove that $f$ has a fixed point in the interval $(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, fixed-points

> A real valued function $f$ is defined on the interval $(-1,2)$. A point $x_0$ is said to be a fixed point of $f$ if $f(x_0)=x_0$. Suppose that $f$ is a differentiable function such that $f(0)>0$ and $f(1)=1$. Show that if $f'(1)>1$, then $f$ has a fixed point in the interval $(0,1)$.

**My approach:**

Let $h(x)=f(x)-x$. Now since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]\implies h$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and since $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)\implies h$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$.

Now $h(0)=f(0)-0=f(0)>0$ and $h(1)=f(1)-1=0$.

Also $h'(x)=f'(x)-1$ $\forall x\in (0,1)$.

This implies that $h'(1)=f'(1)-1>0.$

Therefore by applying MVT on the function $h$ on the interval $[0,1]$ we can conclude that $\exists c\in(0,1)$ such that $$h'(c)=\frac{h(1)-h(0)}{1-0}=-h(0)<0.$$

Therefore we have $h'(c)<0$ and $h'(1)>0$. Therefore by applying IVT on the interval $[c,1]$, we can conclude that $\exists c_1\in (0,1)$ such that $h'(c_1)=0$.

How to proceed after this?

Comment: What does $(-1,2)$ have to do with this problem, past the first sentence?

Comment: @kimchilover likely an interval large enough not to think about what happens at the boundary :) of course, a smaller one would be perfectly sufficient

Comment: With $h'(1)>0$ and $h(1)=1$, can you show there is an $x \in (0,1)$ with $h(x) \lt 0$?

Comment: You say $f$ is defined on $(-1,2)$ in the first sentence, but say its continuous in $[0,1]$ in the next paragraph, do you mean $[0,1]$ all along?

Comment: @Leo, in your example $y'(1)=1$. But, we have assumed that $y'(1)>1$.

Comment: @Sanket Biswas True, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f'(1) = L > 1$, we get that $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1-f(x)}{1-x} = L> 1$, because this is the left-sided derivative.

Thank you @Franklin for asking for a more detailed answer. What follows is precisely that.

Let us use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limits to prove the following statement :

> There exists $x_0 < 1$ such that $\frac{1-f(x_0)}{1-x_0} > 1$ i.e. $f(x_0) < x_0$.

To prove this, we will use the definition of the left sided limit $\lim_{x \to 1^-}$ in the expression  $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1-f(x)}{1-x} = L > 1$. Let us pick $\epsilon = \frac{L-1}{2}$.

By definition (of the left hand limit), there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $\delta > (1-x) > 0$, we have $$\left|\frac{1-f(x)}{1-x} - L\right|< \epsilon = \frac{L-1}{2}$$

Using the triangle inequality, for every $x$ such that $\delta > (1-x) > 0$, $$
\frac{1-f(x)}{1-x} > L - \frac{L-1}{2} = \frac{L+1}{2} > 1   
$$
as $L>1$. Now, if $x_0$ is any point such that $\delta > 1-x_0>0$, then from above, it follows that
$$\frac{1-f(x_0)}{1-x_0} > 1 \implies f(x_0)< x_0$$

where the implication follow by simple algebraic rearrangement.

We are in position to apply the intermediate value theorem. A common trick in proving fixed-point theorems (at the rudimentary level) is to use the intermediate value theorem with the function $g(x) = f(x)- x$, since $g(x)=0$ if and only if $f(x)=x$.

Keeping this heuristic in mind, we let $g(x) = f(x)-x$. Then, by choice, $f(x_0)<x_0$ implies that $g(x_0)<0$, and $f(0)>0$ implies that $g(0)>0$. In particular, we have found an interval $[0,x_0]$ such that :

- $g(0)>0$.
- $g(x_0)<0$.
- $g$ is *continuous* on $[0,x_0]$, since $f$ is differentiable , hence continuous on $[0,x_0]$, the function $h(x)=x$ is continuous on $[0,x_0]$, and $g = f-h$ is the difference of two continuous functions on $[0,x_0]$.

Thus, we can apply the intermediate value theorem to the function $g$ on $[0,x_0]$. This gives us a number $0<y<x_0$ such that $g(y)=0$. By definition of $g$, $f(y)=y$. Finally, since $y \neq 0$ (because $f(0) > 0$) and $x_0<1$, it follows that $y \in (0,x_0) \subset (0,1)$.

That is, we have proved that $y \in (0,1)$ is a fixed point of $f$, as desired.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "definition of limits" ? When we say, "definition of limits" we generally mean $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limits. But I dont get how does that follow from there?

Comment: @Franklin It's been very long since I answered this question, so kindly give me some time to read my answer and I'll be able to address your concern. Thank you for asking.

Comment: Your answer is wonderful as well as elegant. I got it, the thing you did , was taking $\epsilon =L-1$ if $L=f'(1)$ and it follows from there.

Comment: @Franklin Oh yes, that is correct! (Maybe $\epsilon = \frac{L-1}{2}$ if you want to be even safer ,say).

Comment: But the thing, that still bothers me, is that how do you use IVT in $(0,x_0)$  to conclude that $\exists y\in (0,x_0)$ such that $f(y)=y.$ I am so sorry, for the inconvenience, but if possible,  please clarify the last step and I will be indebted to you. Thank you! 

Comment: @Franklin Definitely, I'll do anything that ensures that people are able to make the best of my answer. Really, thank you so much, I'm indebted to your careful analysis of this answer.

Comment: @Franklin You can now look at the IVT part.

Comment: For the IVT part, applying it on $g(x)=f(x)-x$ gives the result as well...

Comment: @Franklin Yes, that works too : just the signs at $0$ and $x_0$ would be inverted.

Comment: Ohh... you edited the OP. This looks good. Thanks a lot, for providing such a detailed answer. +1 from me. However, taking the limit (i.e derivative function of $f(x)$), at $x\to 1_{-}$, is to me, the most critical part of the problem and it seems, completely heuristical. What do you think ?

Comment: @Franklin Here's a "picture" : Draw the graph of the line $x=y$. Now, we're going to try and draw the graph of $f$. $f(0)>0$, so at the point $0$ the graph of $f$ is above the graph of $x=y$.  Next, $f(1)=1$ so the graphs meet at $1$. Finally, what does $f'(1)>1$ mean? It means that the "slope" of $f$ at the point $1$ is *larger* than the slope of the line $x=y$ at the point $1$(which is equal to $1$). Drawing this out, the graph of $f$ is "below" the graph of $x=y$ just before both intersect at $1$. So somewhere between $0$ and $1$, the graph of $f$ must intersect the graph of $x=y$.

Comment: To make all that rigorous, all we need to do is make rigorous the fact that the graph of $f$ is "below" the graph of $x=y$ just before both intersect at $1$. That's why we do what we do, which is to use the limit definition in that particular way and get the point $x_0$. Then the application of the IVT is still somewhat standard (i.e. not the most difficult part of the proof).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed a good answer you posted!...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to prove that $h$ has a root on $(0,1)$. Since $h(1)=0$ and $h'(1)>0$, there is a point $x=1-\epsilon$ where $h(1-\epsilon) < 0$ and now apply the IVT to $h$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f'(1)>1$ and $f(1)=1$ imply $(1-f(x))/(1-x)>1$ in some interval $(1-\delta,1).$ This implies $f(x)<x$ in that interval.